# Замена символов в строке на языке си

Tags: c, строки

решаю такую задачу из лабораторной работы, но уже несколько дней сижу и не могу сделать:

*Строка содержит запись арифметического выражения на языке Си. В выражении могут использоваться операции «+», «-», «*», «%», функции sin(), cos(), tan(). Получить строку, содержащую запись этого выражения на языке Паскаль. (Константы, идентификаторы, операции «+», «-», «*» и функции sin() и cos() на Паскале записываются так же, как на Си, операцию «%» следует заменить на « mod », функции вычисления тангенса в Паскале не существует, нужно использовать отношение синуса к косинусу)*

Пробовал и с функциями библиотеки string, и посимвольным перебором, максимум что вышло это заменить "%" на "mod".
Как мне кажется тут нужно разбить строку на части, которые ограничиваются "%" и "tan", затем поменять уже отдельно их и склеить все это в единую строку.

Comment: Без примера кода или хотя бы словесного описания алгоритма вопрос выглядит как "сделайте за меня", и будет закрыт.

Comment: Я думаю Вам поможет обратная польская запись сделать это))) Надо токо чуть ее допилить)))

Comment: Вам надо разбирать текст на уровне потока *лексем*. Читаете лексему и выводите ее в строку. Если выводите `%`, то заменяете на `mod` (тут просто). А вот  `tan` должен вызывать рекурсивную функцию, которая вернет строку (вероятно, выделяемую malloc) и содержит странслированное скобочное выражение, которое идет после `tan`. Это необходимо, поскольку в аргументе `tan()` может быть выражение, также с `tan()`. Далее вы формируете строку из `sin`, этого результата `/ cos` и опять та же строка с результатом. На верхнем уровне строка добавляется к формируемому результату.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{

    char str[] = "2 + 5 % cos(0.5) / sin(1) + tan(12) % 10";
    char *new_str = (char *) malloc((strlen(str) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    char *leks = (char *) malloc(40 * sizeof(char));

    leks = strtok(str, " ");

    while (leks != NULL)
    {
        if (*leks == '%')
        {
            leks = "mod";
        }

        if (leks[0] == 't')
        {
            int size = 0;
            char *num = (char *) malloc(size * sizeof(char));

            for (int i = 0; i < strlen(leks) + 1; i++)
            {
                if (leks[i + 4] == ')')
                    break;

                num = (char *) realloc(num, ++size * sizeof(char));
                num[i] = leks[i + 4];
            }

            char *sin_cos = (char *) malloc(15 + strlen(num) * 2);
            sin_cos = strcat(sin_cos, "(sin(");
            sin_cos = strcat(sin_cos, num);
            sin_cos = strcat(sin_cos, ") / cos(");
            sin_cos = strcat(sin_cos, num);
            sin_cos = strcat(sin_cos, "))");

            leks = sin_cos;
        }

        new_str = strcat(new_str, leks);
        new_str = strcat(new_str, " ");

        leks = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    printf("new_str = %s\n", new_str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: У вас в коде куча утечек памяти...

Comment: Что это за `char *leks = (char *) malloc(40 * sizeof(char));`, если сразу после него идет `leks = strtok(str, " ");`??? `strcat(new_str, leks);` - а кто вам сказал, что `new_str` хватит места?

Comment: Разумеется и весь подход, использованный в этом коде, совершенно нежизнеспособен и применим только к примитивным примерам.

Comment: Почему бы вам не запрограммировать с использование реальных лексем вашего языка? Т.е. определите лексемы, например -- OPERATION, LEFT_PARENT, RIGHT_PARENT, NUMBER, PARSE_FIN и IDENTIFICATOR (одним из IDENTIFICATOR как раз и будет `tan`, а одной из OPERATION `%`). У лексемы есть ее тип (OPERATION, IDENTIFICATOR и т.д.) и конкретное значение (`+`, `%`, `(`, `sin`, `tan` и т.д.). Лексемы читайте отдельной функцией. При чтении лексемы `(` вызывайте функцию, скажем, `get_par_expr()` (она тоже читает лексемы и может вызывать себя), которая сформирует результат в строке